# I tried all ways, but still my area is calculated wrongly in Postgis

Tags: postgis, geojson, wgs84

I created a very simple polygon in the middle of Germany to demonstrate my problem.

You can visualize it in geojsonlint using the following GeoJSON

```
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[
[10.439844131469727,51.17460781257472],
[10.430574417114258,51.1753073564544],
[10.429565906524658,51.17179607723465],
[10.438792705535889,51.170706315523866],
[10.439372062683105,51.17267055874809],
[10.43975830078125,51.17439256616884],
[10.439844131469727,51.17460781257472]]]G}
```

When calculating the surface with online tools (e.g. http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-google-maps-area-calculator-tool.htm, but I tried several),
I get the following numbers (these are based on a similar drawing of the polygon, but not the exact same one, as I couldn't copy it over to these tools):

- 276583.39 m²
- 0.28 km²
- 68.35 acres
- 27.66 hectares
- 2977118.86 feet²
- 0.08 square nautical miles

Now I want to calculate these areas using POSTGIS, but I always get wrong and not matching numbers.

First I started without transformation using the examples given here:

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html

```
 SELECT ST_Area(the_geom) As sqft, ST_Area(the_geom)*POWER(0.3048,2) As sqm
 FROM (SELECT ST_GeomFromText('
 POLYGON ((51.17460781257472  10.439844131469727,
 51.1753073564544 10.430574417114258, 
 51.17179607723465 10.429565906524658,
 51.170706315523866 10.438792705535889,
 51.17267055874809 0.439372062683105,
 51.17439256616884 10.43975830078125,
 51.17460781257472 10.439844131469727))',4326) ) As foo(the_geom);
```

--> sqft = 3.52643124351653e-05 and sqm = 3.27616182873666e-06

How can I interprete these numbers?
Then I tried to transform it to WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N 32633

```
SELECT ST_Area(the_geom) As sqft, ST_Area(the_geom)*POWER(0.3048,2) As sqm
FROM (SELECT ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('
POLYGON ((51.174661624019286 10.440187454223633,
51.17067940750161 10.438899993896484,
51.17197097486416 10.429544448852539, 
51.17536116708255 10.430488586425781,
51.174661624019286 10.440187454223633))',4326),32633) ) As foo(the_geom);
```

--> sqft = 662918.939349234 and sqm = 61587.1847391195

But even these numbers don't come close.

Comment: You should read that example again. It says it's using sqft just because it's using SRID which have feet as a unit. You're getting square degrees.

Answer (score 2):

The coordinates of the polygon were accidentally loaded as lat,lon instead of lon, lat.

http://postgis.net/2013/08/18/tip_lon_lat
says

*In spatial databases spatial coordinates are in x = longitude, and y = latitude*

Answer (score 1):

I converted the coordinates into EPSG: 31467, see [epsg:31467](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/dhdn-gauss-kruger-zone-3/) which is projected to meters and applies to the area of Germany covered by your geometry.

```
select st_area(st_transform(st_setsrid(st_geomfromtext('POLYGON((10.439844131469727    
  51.17460781257472,10.430574417114258 51.1753073564544,10.429565906524658
  51.17179607723465,10.438792705535889 51.170706315523866, 10.439372062683105 
  51.17267055874809, 10.43975830078125 51.17439256616884, 10.439844131469727 
  51.17460781257472))'),4326),31467));
```

and got the answer: 274442.27 m<sup>2</sup> which is within 0.007% of your original answer.

Measurements are usually more accurate in projected coordinate systems that use a geoid appropriate to that region. If you run this query on the spatial reference system table in Postgis for that projection:

```
 select * from spatial_ref_sys where srid=31467;
```

you will see some more details, such as the fact that it uses the Bessel 1841 spheroid.

EDIT: your original geojson has coordinates in x/y, but for some reason you flipped them when putting them into Postgis.

Comment: wow! Thank you very much, John. I didn't know that I needed to set the SRID again.

Comment: @user3633854 you are very welcome -- have a look at http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html. Welcome to SO too. If this has solved you issue, could you possibly consider accepting the answer? It helps others know it was correct and gives credit for the time put in :-)

Comment: sorry, as I still had problems, I looked deeper into the issue and found out, that you flipped the x/y coordinates. Therefore the source of my problem was that I stored the polygon with latitude/longitude, but not with longitude/latitude. Thank you by pointing into the right direction!

Comment: @user3633854. Oh, yes, I flipped them in my answer and forgot to mention it. This is a common problem as people say lat/lon, when really it should be lon/lat. Also, your original geojson was the correct way round.

Comment: @user3633854. Your area measurements would be inaccurate using UTM also, as UTM areas cover such a large area, they are subject to high scale distortion. The SRS 31467 I suggested, will give you much better results for Germany.